Find line segment from $z_1=1$ to $z_2=i$
I need to verify if a point lies on the line segment from $z_1=1$ to $z_2=i$. However, I'm not sure if I can use the usual equation of a line, and I've been searching online, but they provide an equation which is ax+by=c, but they don't explain how to find these variables a,b,c. As well I know there is another way to find this line, which would be $tz_1+(1-t)z_2$ for t $ \in [0,1]$, but I don't know how to substitute the values of my complex point into this equation.
I'm not sure if anyone can help me.

What's the point?    This should be easy.   One way:   use the usual equation for a line, and substitute the coordinates.

@calcll  The point is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} + \frac{i}{\sqrt{6}}$, but I didn't know how to find the equation of the line, but if I can used the usual that's fine thx

The equation is $y=-x+1.$

Or use $t\cdot i+(1-t)\cdot1, 0\le t\le1.$
Since we must have $t=\frac 1{\sqrt 6},$ we get $\frac 1{\sqrt 6}i+\frac {\sqrt6-1}{\sqrt 6}\neq \frac 1{\sqrt 6}i+\frac 1{\sqrt 6}.$
